# How do I write an overload operator where both arguments are interface

Tags: c#, interface, operators, operator-overloading

I'm using interface for most of my stuff.  I can't find a way to create an overload operator   + that would allow me to perform an addition on any objects implementing the IPoint interface

Code

```
interface IPoint
{
    double X { get; set; }
    double Y { get; set; }
}
```

```
class Point : IPoint
{
   double X { get; set; }
   double Y { get; set; }

   //How and where do I create this operator/extension  ???
   public static IPoint operator + (IPoint a,IPoint b)
   {
     return Add(a,b);
   }

   public static IPoint Add(IPoint a,IPoint b)
   {
      return new Point { X = a.X + b.X, Y = a.Y + b.Y };
   } 
}

   //Dumb use case :
public class Test
{
   IPoint _currentLocation;

   public Test(IPoint initialLocation)
   {
     _currentLocation = intialLocation
   }
   public MoveOf(IPoint movement)
   {

      _currentLocation = _currentLocation + intialLocation;
     //Much cleaner/user-friendly than _currentLocation = Point.Add(_currentLocation,intialLocation); 
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do this in C# right now. We considered adding this feature to C# 4.0 in the form of "extension operators", but it was not a high enough priority feature and it got cut. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Imagine if you have two IPoint instances, a and b, both of different classes (which implement IPoint). Now call "a + b". Which operator+ gets called? Which concrete type is returned?

Edit: Sorry, to clarify to your comment, "Not in C# as it stands". I have some philipsophical debate as to whether you should even be able to do this, as I suspect you can create some significant confusion.

Comment: That is the point of the question : Is there a way to write an overload (like in C++) that is NOT attached to a specific class.  In  my case, I want the operator I'm defining to be called when 2 instance of IPoint are called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you're asking, I've looked in the past and come up empty.  The problem is, even in your example of using `.Add` is that you still need to cast the `movement` parameter to a `Point Type` to have access to that method.  This, I believe is a limitation of C#, if I'm wrong I'd be very happy to know about it.

What I would suggest is that if you **know** you are *always* going to get a `Point Type` in `MoveOf` then it would be safe to always cast it to `Point` inside the method, however if this is the case then you should be accepting `Point` as the parameter.

The only other thing I can say is that if you are creating a `Point Type` initially and passing that to `MoveOf`, you could check the type of `movement` inside `MoveOf` before casting it.  The problem here of course is that you would eventually have to do this for **all** types that inherit from `IPoint` and use the `MoveOf` method.